# Mathematical explanation how Random Forest works

Tags: random-forest

I would need to carefully understand the mathematical background behind the RF prediction.
I am not sure if this is the right website to post this question, but I will take the chance.

Namely, I am not sure how to express this in mathematical terms how RF predict.
Let's say we have a RF with three trees resulting with predictions and the classification task.

```
T1: 1 0 0 1 0 
T2: 1 0 1 1 0
T3: 0 1 1 1 1
-------------
R : 1 0 1 1 0
```

Note how the end result is what is more close to the average value.
How would you define this mathematically?

Comment: This is probably the right forum but what is your question exactly?

Comment: what is the math behind the average, behind the variance reducing